# Coordinates vs. parametrization of a worldsheet

Tags: differential-geometry, metric-tensor, string-theory, coordinate-systems

In introductory string theory, the worldsheet is described (e.g. Tong, Polchinski) as a surface $X^\mu(\tau,\sigma)$ in Minkowski spacetime indexed by two parameters: $(\tau,\sigma)$. Now, I initially wrote this off as classic abuse of notation, where we're taking $X^\mu(\tau,\sigma)$ to be shorthand for $X^\mu(S(\tau,\sigma))$ where $S:\mathbb{R}^2\to M$ is the map to the "abstract" worldsheet and $X^\mu :M\to\mathbb{R}^4$ is the (homeomorphism defined by the) chart. However, then I was introduced to the induced metric on the worldsheet,$$\gamma_{\alpha\beta}=\frac{\partial X^\mu}{\partial\sigma^\alpha}\frac{\partial X^\nu}{\partial\sigma^\beta}\eta_{\mu\nu},$$ and I realized the $\sigma^\alpha\in\{\tau,\sigma\}$ are meant to be understood as genuine *coordinates*, despite the fact they were clearly introduced as parameters. But the parameters and coordinates need not have anything to do with each other. I could happily reparametrize the worldsheet and leave the chart alone and that obviously wouldn't be a coordinate transformation right?

The only way I can make sense of this is if really $X^\mu :\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^4$ and $X^\mu(\tau,\sigma)$ is shorthand for $X^\mu[\varphi(S(\tau,\sigma))]$ with the worldsheet chart $\varphi=S^{-1}$. Then whenever we perform a reparameterization we modify $S$ and $\varphi$ simultaneously so that it is a genuine coordinate transformation. As in, the reparametrization takes us from $S(\tau,\sigma)\rightarrow S^\prime(\tau^\prime,\sigma^\prime)$, and we modify the chart, $S^{-1}(p)\rightarrow (S^\prime)^{-1}(p)$ so that rather than a given point mapping to the coordinates $(\tau,\sigma)$ it maps to $(\tau^\prime,\sigma^\prime)$. So in effect, we simply choose the coordinates to numerically coincide with the parameters.

Is this correct or am I overthinking it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the core issue of your question is the sentence *"But the parameters and coordinates need not have anything to do with each other".* This is not true. If $\cal M$ is a smooth manifold, $U\subset \cal M$ is an open subset on which we define a coordinate chart $x: U\to \mathbb{R}^D$ the inverse $x^{-1}:\mathbb{R}^D\to U$ is called the associated parameterization. Coordinates and parameters are distinct names for the same thing.

The origin of this issue is probably because you recall that a parameterized curve is a map $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ and then you seem to think that an embedding $\phi:\Sigma\to {\cal M}$ presuposes a parameterization. That is not true. Given one embedding $\phi : \Sigma\to {\cal M}$ you will have a parameterization *when you introduce coordinates on $\Sigma$*. In that setting a reparameterization is just a change of coordinates in $\Sigma$.

In the parameterized curve story, the thing is that one implicitly assumes that one is using the trivial chart in $\mathbb{R}$, namely $t: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ given as the identity element. A reparameterization, as you know from the study of curves, is then given by a change of coordinates.

So in summary: an embedding is just one smooth injective immersion which is a homeomorphism onto its image. An embedding exists independently of any choice of parameterization. When you introduce coordinates on the domain you then have a parameterization of the embedded submanifold.

Comment: "*'But the parameters and coordinates need not have anything to do with each other'. This is not true.*"

But aren't you just describing a particular choice of parametrization, the one that makes the parameters and coordinates equal? This is in fact precisely the same thing I decribe in the question. But given some suitable curve, I can choose to parameterize it with, say, values in the interval $(0,1)$, or in the interval $(-\infty,\infty)$. These choices have nothing to do with the coordinates I cover the manifold with.

Comment: This is why I'm confused, because I understand a parameterized curve to be a map $\gamma :\mathbb{R}\to\mathcal{M}$. To me a reparameterization only changes what values in $\mathbb{R}$ send you to which points along the curve, it doesn't effect the coordinates of those points. If the chart being the inverse of the worldsheet map is just something that is meant to be implied, then I'm fine with that, but I wanted to be sure because it's an important distinction imo.

Comment: I think I see now what you are confused about. We have *two manifolds* in this discussion. For the curve we have $\mathbb{R}$ and $M$. The embedding is a map from one into the other $\gamma:\mathbb{R}\to M$. Now the parameterization is associated to coordinates in $\mathbb{R}$ and not in $M$. The coordinates of $M$ are really unrelated, but in this whole discussion we are talking about the coordinates in the domain of the embedding.

Comment: Just to make my point clear and expand a little. The first paragraph of my answer applies to *any* manifold and is just a question of terminology: you have a manifold, then coordinates and parameters mean the same thing. But when I discuss one embedded submanifold $\phi:\Sigma\to M$ I have two manifolds in the discussion. For the curve or the worldsheet when we say that the parameters are coordinates we are referring to the coordinates on $\Sigma$, not on $M$. In other words parameters and coordinates **both for $\Sigma$** are the same, not parameters for $\Sigma$ and coordinates for $M$.

Comment: Ahh, of course. I guess I was indeed overthinking it :) Cheers!

Comment: @KrisWalker happy that it helped. Best wishes!